# How To Enable Different Configurations for Different Environments by Using Feature Flagging in Java

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX application which runs on several servers, I want to enable\disable some of the features according to specific properties, the value of the properties will not be changed once the application is up.

eg: the features 1,2,3 of the application are supposed to work on server 1, but on server 2 only features 2,3 are supposed to work, etc.

I researched about Feature Flagging\Feature Toggles on java for my needs but:

Most of the examples I read was about web applications and rest calls, is there any example that use no-web application?

In addition, I didn't find any example\explanation how to manage feature flagging on several servers\environments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let me recommend [ff4j](https://github.com/ff4j/ff4j). It works on toggles. One toggle = one feature. In the code it is as simple as checking if given toggle is enabled or disabled.

As for management in runtime, the toggles are available as JMX parameters, so you can switch them on your machines as you choose.